# Question about Hi-Res Audio printed on headphone box

Tags: headphones

I've noticed that the Sennheiser HD 650 has Hi-Res Audio printed on the box but the ATH-AD2000X box doesn't seem to have that. I was wondering what that meant for the ATH-AD2000X, is it not also Hi-Res Audio?

[image: Sennheiser headphones]

Comment: Sorry, I modified my question now.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-resolution_audio

Comment: It's marketing.